# How can I tell if a memory leak is in user space or kernel space?

Tags: memory, wayland, opengl

I have a large multi-threaded open source application which uses proprietary OpenGL libraries, Wayland Weston, and a proprietary graphics driver in the Linux kernel.  The drivers are currently under development, so there is a strong possibility that they have errors.

I have observed the following symptoms:

1. Free memory (`free -m`) is continuously consumed while running my application. At a steady state, it consumes about 1MB/5minutes.
2. If I stop and start my application continuously, I am able to accelerate the rate of memory loss. It looks like I lose about 0.5MB every time I restart the application.
3. When I stop my application, the memory is not returned to the system. The memory is returned only after a power cycle.
4. I have started to log memory usage, as well as taking snapshots of `/proc/<pid>/smaps`. I can see which thread consumes the memory, and I will  investigate further.
5. inspection of the smaps file shows that, over time, the older snapshot has consumed more memory. There are also more `anon_inode:dmabuf` entries in the older snapshot, and this looks similar to these issues:

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28097766/where-does-the-dev-zero-deleted-anon-inodedmabuf-comes-from-in-proc-p

   https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100298

Is this memory leak more likely to be a user space memory leak or a kernel memory leak?

What other diagnostics can I perform to narrow down the likely source of leaks?

Answer (score 1):

Is the application doing any anonymous memory allocations thru mmap()?
Any data or log files being written to a RAM disk?
Got threads that are constantly starting and finishing?  Handling thread terminations correctly?  (Been there, found that as a leak.)
If you wait a bit, does kernel memory usage drop off as dynamic structures get released?

I would put the odds of who is leaking memory at better than 99% in favor of the application.

Comment: I trust the application more than the libraries and kernel driver. It's a very large application, in use on many mass produced products.

At this point, I'd like to narrow it down to either user space, or kernel space>

BTW, I did find that another application was crashing, and creating core dumps in /tmp, so that explains some of the other memory loss.

Comment: I am seeing anon allocations in the smaps files, and the anon allocations are the ones which are growing over time. When I do the accelerated test, I can't use the smaps logging because the PID changes each time.   Kernel memory usage does drop off over time in the single-run test. It does stabilise.